How to print constexpr in C23 at compile-time?
I'm migrating my codebase from C17 to C23 on ARM-GCC and would like to be able to print the evaluation of constexpr calculations at compile-time for debugging purposes.
In C17, I used #pragma message with a stringified, expanded version of my macro. Trying this in C23 using arm-none-eabi-gcc version 14.2.Rel1
I've seen some examples  using templates with C++ but obviously that won't work for C.
For example, define printing vs. constexpr printing:
#define VALUE1 10
#define VALUE2 (VALUE1 + 5)
#define DEFINE_VALUE (VALUE2 * 2)

constexpr int val1 = 10;
constexpr int val2 = val1 + 5;
constexpr int constexpr_val = val2 * 2;

#define EXPAND(x) x
#define DEFINE_VALUE_EXPANDED EXPAND(DEFINE_VALUE)

#define STRINGIFY(x) #x
#define TOSTRING(x) STRINGIFY(x)

#pragma message("DEFINE_VALUE_EXPANDED is " TOSTRING(DEFINE_VALUE_EXPANDED))
#pragma message("constexpr_val is " TOSTRING(constexpr_val))

Results in:
src/io/test.c:130:9: note: '#pragma message: DEFINE_VALUE_EXPANDED is ((10 + 5) * 2)'
  130 | #pragma message("DEFINE_VALUE_EXPANDED is " TOSTRING(DEFINE_VALUE_EXPANDED))
      |         ^~~~~~~
src/io/test.c:131:9: note: '#pragma message: constexpr_val is constexpr_val'
  131 | #pragma message("constexpr_val is " TOSTRING(constexpr_val))
      |         ^~~~~~~

Ideally would print 30 in both cases. The way the define prints is ok, but the constexpr is printing as the string itself.

Often the answer for "how do I do it at compile-time" is "you can't". If the compilation is successful, however, you can usually generate an array literal containing characters, and extract it using the strings tool. This is a much better oracle than static_assert or similar.

C the standard does not have any way to do that because it does not equate "constexpr" with "compile time", or indeed deal with "compile time" at all.

It's way too early to migrate to C23. The standard itself will likely get a bunch of technical corrigendums. In addition the latest gcc 14.2 is a complete bug fest. You can't use any of this shoddy prototype technology yet, it's just one big safety hazard for now.

@n.m.couldbeanAI: Re “C the standard does not have any way to do that because it does not equate "constexpr" with "compile time", or indeed deal with "compile time" at all”: Yes, it does. C 2024 6.2.4 says “…  if it is specified with constexpr the initializer is evaluated once at translation time…”

@EricPostpischil I stand corrected

Often the answer is, build your own tool.  As part of the make process you can create a header file with calculated values.  I would guess that some gcc intermediate file will make the computations available (alternatively you can use other tools like bc, perl, python, shell math, etc).  If your wish it to abort the build process when values are not within design range, this is the way to go.  Tools vendors (compiler designers) would find this as obvious; a reason why the standard might not provide it.

The C standard does not provide a way to display the results of constant expressions at compile time. With GCC and Clang, you do this using the __asm__ construct with an immediate operand, discussed here and here.

The referenced answers are only to generate synthetic output that is then parsed.  For examples of structure layout by the compiler, this makes more sense.  If the parameters are a static configuration of a system design such as filters taps, OS or TCP/IP stack, then it is not needed to involve the compiler (which could be more 'portable' as in not tied to a compiler).
